# ¿Como reemplazar xa0 por espacio en blanco en python?

Tags: python, csv

Buen día a todos, mi duda es la siguiente. Tengo un script en python, el  cual funciona, pero el detalle es que en lugar de los espacios en blanco aparece "\xa0" a la hora de imprimir y quisiera quitarlo. El script lo que hace básicamente es leer un csv. Otra cosa, es que intenté colocar  "print(string.strip(row))", no sé si está bien o no, apenas estoy empezando a usar python. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',', quotechar=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: el `\xa0` es el codigo `hexadecimal` de `espacio` puedes hacer `row.strip()`

Comment: Si lo pongo tal cual, me aparece esto.
'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
lo pongo de esta forma
"print(row.strip())"

Comment: podrias agregar un minimo de tu `test.csv` a tu pregunta para darte una respuesta mas comcreta!

Comment: Pues lo que tengo en el test.csv es literal esto

Prueba 1x1, Prueba 1x2, Prueba 1x3
Prueba 2x1, Prueba 2x2, Prueba 2x3
Prueba 3x1, Prueba 3x2, Prueba 3x3

Y lo que imprime es 

'Prueba\xa01x1','Prueba\xa01x2','Prueba\xa01x3'

Comment: intenga agregado `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` al inico de tu documento!

Comment: Ya lo agregué y nop, no cambió en nada.

Comment: @Bryro En Python 3 no es necesario especificar codificación UTF-8, ya que es la que se supone por defecto. Por otro lado ese comentario serviría en todo caso para que Python decodificara correctamente los caracteres utf8 que aparecieran _formando parte del código fuente_, pero no es este el caso, ya que aquí el código "raro" aparece en un .csv, externo al fuente, y sobre él ese comentario no tiene influencia. Tendría que usar el parámetro `encoding` en el `open()`. De todas formas tampoco es un problema de encoding, ya que el carácter es leido correctamente, pero es un espacio "especial"

Answer (score 1):

El prefijo `\x` delante de dos dígitos es usado por Python para mostrar un carácter no-ascii y no imprimible, cuando está mostrando la representación interna de una cadena. En el caso de Python 2 lo que va tras la `\x` es el código hexadecimal de un byte, el byte que no pudo ser interpretado como texto. En caso de Python 3 lo que va tras el `\x` es el código hexadecimal de un carácter Unicode.

No especificas si se trata de python2 o 3, pero a juzgar por el `print()` supondré que es Python3. En este caso estás viendo el código Unicode `U+00A0`, que es el [espacio irrompible](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) utilizado en algunos editores cuando se quiere poner un espacio que no debe romperse por un cambio de línea, es decir, que conserva juntas en la misma línea las dos palabras que le rodean.

Si no quieres tener este tipo de espacios en tu cadena, lo más sencillo es que los reemplaces por espacios normales, así:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',', quotechar=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        row = [elemento.replace("\xa0", " ") for elemento in row]
        print(row)
```

Si el espacio estaba al inicio o al final de la cadena, puedes eliminarlo con `.strip()`, como te han indicado en algún comentario. Pero ya que se trata de un espacio irrompible, no le veo mucho sentido a que aparezca al inicio o al final.

En todo caso, la secuencia `\xa0` era visible sólo porque estabas imprimiendo `row`, que no es una cadena, sino una lista de ellas, y por tanto python te muestra separadas por comas y entre corchetes, todas las cadenas que hay en esa fila, cada una de ellas entrecomillada y usando su representación interna.

Si en lugar de imprimir `row` (que es una lista)  hicieras un bucle para imprimir cada uno de los elementos de `row` (que son cadenas), entonces python ya no mostrará la representación interna de los caracteres no imprimibles, y el carácter `\xa0` será mostrado (aparentemente) como un carácter normal. Compara esto:

```
>>> lista = [ 'texto\xa0otro' ]
>>> print(lista)
['texto\xa0otro']
>>> print(repr(lista[0]))
'texto\xa0otro'
>>> print(lista[0])
texto otro
```

Como ves, al mostrar la cadena hay un espacio entre `texto` y `otro`. No obstante no es un espacio normal. Si seleccionas y copias ese texto para pegarlo en otra aplicación, iría el carácter "espacio irrompible", si bien es imposible diferenciarlos sin ver sus códigos (por eso Python elige mostrarlo como `\xa0` cuando está mostrando la representación interna de la cadena, para que sea posible distinguirlo del espacio normal).

Por tanto en tu caso podrías imprimir los contenidos de cada fila, sin necesidad de reemplazarlos con espacios, haciendo esto:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',', quotechar=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        for elemento in fila:
            print(elemento, end=" ")
        print()
```

(**nota** lo de `end=" "` es para que en lugar de un salto de línea, se añada un espacio tras cada elemento impreso).

Comment: @abuflia row es un arreglo no podras usar a replace `rows = [ x.replace("\xa0", " ") for x in row ]`

Comment: @Bryro Ah, tienes toda la razón, no me di cuenta de que `row` era una lista. He corregido la respuesta y aprovechado para ampliarla, a la vista de esta información. Gracias.